# Getting Error Code 404 while creating new react app

Tags: reactjs, npm, npm-install

I'm getting Error Code 404 Forbidden while creating a new react app.

Not sure if this is some kind of permission issue as I am doing this on my office system.
This is the command I used and the log file:

```
  npx create-react-app MyApp

    0 info it worked if it ends with ok
    1 verbose cli [ 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
    1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
    1 verbose cli   'install',
    1 verbose cli   'create-react-app@latest',
    1 verbose cli   '--global',
    1 verbose cli   '--prefix',
    1 verbose cli   'C:\\Users\\gbhanda1\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm-cache\\_npx\\41680',
    1 verbose cli   '--loglevel',
    1 verbose cli   'error',
    1 verbose cli   '--json' ]
    2 info using npm@6.4.1
    3 info using node@v11.3.0
    4 verbose npm-session 7cf6be9634f65a6a
    5 silly install loadCurrentTree
    6 silly install readGlobalPackageData
    7 http fetch GET 403 https://registry.npmjs.org/create-react-app 598ms
    8 silly fetchPackageMetaData error for create-react-app@latest 403 Forbidden: create-react-app@latest
    9 timing stage:rollbackFailedOptional Completed in 6ms
    10 timing stage:runTopLevelLifecycles Completed in 3014ms
    11 verbose stack Error: 403 Forbidden: create-react-app@latest
    11 verbose stack     at fetch.then.res (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\pacote\lib\fetchers\registry\fetch.js:42:19)
    11 verbose stack     at tryCatcher (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\util.js:16:23)
    11 verbose stack     at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:512:31)
    11 verbose stack     at Promise._settlePromise (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:569:18)
    11 verbose stack     at Promise._settlePromise0 (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:614:10)
    11 verbose stack     at Promise._settlePromises (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:693:18)
    11 verbose stack     at Async._drainQueue (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\async.js:133:16)
    11 verbose stack     at Async._drainQueues (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\async.js:143:10)
    11 verbose stack     at Immediate.Async.drainQueues [as _onImmediate] (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\async.js:17:14)
    11 verbose stack     at processImmediate (timers.js:632:19)
    12 verbose cwd C:\Users\gbhanda1
    13 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.17134
    14 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "create-react-app@latest" "--global" "--prefix" "C:\\Users\\gbhanda1\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm-cache\\_npx\\41680" "--loglevel" "error" "--json"
    15 verbose node v11.3.0
    16 verbose npm  v6.4.1
    17 error code E403
    18 error 403 Forbidden: create-react-app@latest
    19 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Comment: Do you are logged at your npm account? Maybe your company has a VPN or just enables you to download dependencies from a private registry (or a private npm account).

Comment: I am not sure but i am connected to VPN. Do you think that might be the issue?

Comment: Not being in the VPN itself... but from where you download your dependencies, there is any `.npmrc` file in the other projects? your some sort of registry configuration on the `package.json`?

Comment: You are probably being routed to your internal company npm registry, and it gives you 404

Comment: minor text adjustments

Comment: Thanks All.It was a registry problem,Now i am able to install libraries using npm command after changing registry to our company repository.